# Katalon Studio [Mobile Testing] Unable to login when executing the test case for login functionality

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, mobile-application, katalon-studio

Login functionality: we’re connected to Firebase and using Firebase Authentication.

**Summary**:
I’ve been trying to automate the login screen of our app, but every time I execute the test case, the app returns an error (see the hyperlink below).

**Steps I’ve Done**:

- Successfully recorded the steps for login screen (able to input the
  username and password via OKTA and app was redirected to the main
  screen)
- Played the recorded test case

**Solutions I have tried**:

- added Firebase jar files to the external
- libraries ticked “Bypass certificate validation”

I was wondering as well, does Katalon generate their own SHA-1 hash? I’ve noticed that I didn’t encounter any errors when recording the steps after I added the Firebase jar files, but when I play the recorded steps, I always encounter the error.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJM2b.jpg)